# download bottom after filter dataset

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to download my file after filtering my data. when i run the below code the result is the only empty file is downloaded (not the filtered data).

Please note that this is multiple shiny app not a single one.

the first part is the UI and second part is the server.

please see the code below:

```
library(shiny)
#library(DT)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)



#UI

fluidPage(
  titlePanel("IN_PATIENT"),
  
  # Create a new Row in the UI for selectInputs
  fluidRow(
    column(2,selectInput("HOSPITAL_NAME",
                       "Hospital Name:",
                       c("All",
                         unique(as.character(IN_PATIENT$HOSPITAL_NAME))))
    ),
    column(2,selectInput("FINAL_GENDER",
                       "Gender:",
                       c("All",
                         unique(as.character(IN_PATIENT$FINAL_GENDER))))
    ),
    column(2,selectInput("FINAL_NATIONALITY_STATUS",
                       "Nationality Status:",
                       c("All",
                         unique(as.character(IN_PATIENT$FINAL_NATIONALITY_STATUS))))
    )
  ),
  
  # Button
  downloadButton("downloadData", "Download"),
 
    DT::dataTableOutput("table")
)



#Server
function(input, output,session) {
  
  # Filter data based on selections
  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable(DT::datatable({
    df <- IN_PATIENT
    if (input$HOSPITAL_NAME != "All") {
      df <- df[df$HOSPITAL_NAME == input$HOSPITAL_NAME,]
    }
    if (input$FINAL_GENDER != "All") {
      df <- df[df$FINAL_GENDER == input$FINAL_GENDER,]
    }
    if (input$FINAL_NATIONALITY_STATUS != "All") {
      df <- df[df$FINAL_NATIONALITY_STATUS == input$FINAL_NATIONALITY_STATUS,]
    }
    df
 
  }))
  

  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste("df-",Sys.Date(), ".csv", sep = "")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(df, file, row.names = FALSE)
    }
  )
    
}
```

Comment: Please provide a working example of your shiny app as it is now.

Comment: you have call the function content(). moreover the fuctions filename and content do not know df.

Comment: You need to separate the creation of your `df` (make it reactive, not static) from its presentation.  At the moment, `df` is local to `output$table`, even though you (attempt to) return it from your `renderDataTable`.

Comment: can you please reflect your comments on the code, because i am not expert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't provide sample data, I made test data with `mtcars`. The best solution in Shiny is to make your data as a reactive object that is passed to `renderDT` and `downloadHandler`:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

IN_PATIENT <- mtcars %>% tibble::rownames_to_column() %>% rename(HOSPITAL_NAME = rowname,
                                                         FINAL_GENDER = vs,
                                                         FINAL_NATIONALITY_STATUS = carb)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("IN_PATIENT"),
  
  # Create a new Row in the UI for selectInputs
  fluidRow(
    column(2,selectInput("HOSPITAL_NAME",
                         "Hospital Name:",
                         c("All",
                           unique(as.character(IN_PATIENT$HOSPITAL_NAME))))
    ),
    column(2,selectInput("FINAL_GENDER",
                         "Gender:",
                         c("All",
                           unique(as.character(IN_PATIENT$FINAL_GENDER))))
    ),
    column(2,selectInput("FINAL_NATIONALITY_STATUS",
                         "Nationality Status:",
                         c("All",
                           unique(as.character(IN_PATIENT$FINAL_NATIONALITY_STATUS))))
    )
  ),
  
  # Button
  downloadButton("downloadData", "Download"),
 
  DT::DTOutput("table")
)

#Server
server <- function(input, output,session) {
    
  df <- reactive({
    df <- IN_PATIENT
  if (input$HOSPITAL_NAME != "All") {
    df <- df[df$HOSPITAL_NAME == input$HOSPITAL_NAME,]
  }
  if (input$FINAL_GENDER != "All") {
    df <- df[df$FINAL_GENDER == input$FINAL_GENDER,]
  }
  if (input$FINAL_NATIONALITY_STATUS != "All") {
    df <- df[df$FINAL_NATIONALITY_STATUS == input$FINAL_NATIONALITY_STATUS,]
  }
  df
  })
  
  # Filter data based on selections
  output$table <- DT::renderDT(datatable(df()))
  
  
  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste("df-",Sys.Date(), ".csv", sep = "")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(df(), file, row.names = FALSE)
    })
  
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```